# Is there any elegant way to handle both a command and click event in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, click

I have a custom control in my WPF application, which has an **Apply** button. When the user clicks the button, I want to execute a command on my view-model (business logic), but also I want to perform some events for the user interface.

It seems to me that if I use the `Command` property, I can't use the `Click` event handler. But, I really don't want to mix my logic together (some of the logic is business logic, some is UI logic).

For now, I've settled on calling the `ICommand.Execute` method from code behind and using the `Click` event. The problem with this is now I can't take advantage of the `ICommand.CanExecute` method.

```
public class OrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DelegateCommand ProcessCommand { get; private set; }

    public void Process(object parameter)
    {
        // Business logic here...
    }
}

<Button Click="OnProcess_Click" />

public void OnProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ProcessCommand.Execute();

    // Do UI specific stuff...
}
```

---

I feel like the way I'm doing it is just bad, especially because I lost the entire `ICommand.CanExecute` benefits, but I'm not sure what else I can do here.

Update: I thought it would be worth mentioning that I prefer that I want my command to execute prior to the UI logic would, not sure if that changes things up.

Comment: Did you consider an attached behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to invoke your `ProccessCommand`:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ProcessCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a `Command` Property of Button to the command in your view, which performs the same logic as your current event handler. Benefit from that, is a possibility of defining `CanExecute` which toggles Button Enabled state. That way you could propagate the CanExecute logic from your ViewModel's command. For example:

You could have a command on your root control:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ProcessCommand, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The above snippet works for control having `x:Name="root"`, but you can name it whatever you want. Or you can chose another way of navigating to the root control having your view command defined in code-behind. The command could be as follows:

```
    private ICommand _processCommand;

    public ICommand ProcessCommand
    {
        get { return _processCommand ?? (_processCommand = new DelegateCommand(Process, CanProcess)); }
    }

    private bool CanProcess(object obj)
    {
        return ViewModel.ProcessCommand.CanExecute(obj);
    }

    private void Process(object obj)
    {
        ViewModel.ProcessCommand.Execute(obj);

        // Do UI specific stuff...
    }
```

This way, you are reusing the full functionality of your ViewModel command and are able to extend it the way you want. The execution order is guaranteed as well.